# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' when working with .htaccess RewriteRule flatlinks

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im trying to make flat links to my site, and thats why i started to make .htaccess file in my root directory. 

First i redirect to https protocol without subdomain www - and thats works right.

Second im trying to make three RewriteRules
first when there is one option second when there are two option and third if there is some text after second option slash

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /index.php

    #redirect to right protocol and without www subdomain

    #check if https is off
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    #or added www to domain name
    RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
    #if one of them - then redirect to https withot www
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


    #flatlink rewrite rules

    #if https://domain.com/option_name OR https://domain.com/option_name/ 
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$    index.php?option=$1 [NC,L]

    #if https://domain.com/option_name/some_id OR https://domain.com/option_name/some_id/
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$    index.php?option=$1&id=$2  [NC,L]

    #if after second slash is some other text just ignore it
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)    index.php?izvele=$1&galda_id=$2  [NC,L]
```

So the problem is when there is only the first of the flatlink rewrite rules everithing works as expected but when i uncoment second only or second and third rule then redirecting work as expected but stiles and javascript is not loaded and console shows this error - SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Another thing that i seen and dont know why this happens is with RewriteBase - if i make it

```
    RewriteBase /
```

then in first flatlink rule option is not passed as option_name but index.php

So i would be whery thankful if someone could point me in right direction to solve this problem.

Comment: `https://domain.com/option_name` … and you have an option name like `myscript.js`, don't you?

Comment: no option_name is choice name like https://domain.com/profile

Comment: Consider the difference between your intentions for the URL format and what you have actually written as the src to a script element.

Comment: So the request for .css and .js also goes throught these rules? So i need to exclude my .css and .js directory from metting these rules?

Comment: So i need just add these? RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d